# Array notation for pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I made a function that  returns a pointer to a newly created matrix. Now I want this function to return an error code of type `status_t` instead of the pointer. To do this, another pointer level has to be added and the matrix has to be returned by reference. However, I can't understand why a segmentation error appears. Here is part of my working code (a) and my failed attempt (b):

(a)

```c
int **create_matrix(size_t dimension) {
    int **p;
    size_t e;
    size_t h;

    if (dimension == 0)
        return NULL;

    for (h = 0; h < dimension; ++h) {
        if ((p[h] = malloc(dimension * sizeof(int))) == NULL) { 
            for (e = h; e >= 0; --e) {  
                free(p[e]);
                p[e] = NULL;
            } <-------- missing closing brace
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

(b)

```c
status_t create_matrix(size_t dimension, int ***p) {
    size_t e;
    size_t h;

    if (p == NULL)
        return ERROR_NULL_POINTER;

    for (h = 0; h < dimension; ++h) {
        if (((*p)[h] = malloc(dimension * sizeof(int))) == NULL) { 
            for (e = h; e >= 0; --e) {  
                free((*p)[e]);
                (*p)[e] = NULL;
            } <-------- missing closing brace
            return ERROR_NO_MEMORY;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling `free()` when you *create* a matrix?

Comment: If malloc fails no there will be memory leaks. I'm trying to avoid this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) isn't exactly "working":

For one thing, it has more `{` than `}`, so it doesn't even compile. You probably forgot to terminate your outer `for` loop.

```
int ** p;
...
    if ((p[h]=...))
```

This dereferences `p` before it was initialized. Using the value of an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. You need to assign something to `p` before you use it (probably by dynamically allocating another array).

To determine whether version (b) has the same issue, we'd have to see the calling code, but at a guess it's also UB.

There's another problem in the inner loop:

```
        for (e = h; e >= 0; --e)
```

`e` is a `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type, so the condition `e >= 0` is always true.

What compiler (and compiler options) are you using? With `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` I get [warnings for both of these](https://tio.run/##ZVDBasMwDL37KwS7xCkpu7vuF5Texg6lFM9RakPiBMeFspBfnydnbbISgYzQe3pPsi6uWsf4Zp2ubyXCrg9lbb@2Zs@YdQHyHLRHFfDSqODtPevtN14ClLZB19vW8eHJ6wR7gDhXRjDSqSCb@SAlvHMGFB7DzTs4fhwORKtaD5kBQgUY2C0OAjYbw9kwzSStrDuZs2xUXbd6Ec6TZVtltA3nXMok@@eTYoC5TDGZIZkZAQj7ybQokL@QBsqXxjTpEWkBPHOxwlJbPs5ZgauL/wPjwh/ZyJ5E@tIxxh9d1erax@KTTqYX78GrWHRYKhes/gU).

A fixed version would look like this:

```
int **create_matrix(size_t dimension) {
    int **p = calloc(dimension, sizeof *p);
    if (!p) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
        if (!(p[i] = calloc(dimension, sizeof *p[i]))) {
            while (i--) {
                free(p[i]);
            }
            free(p);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

Version (b) can then be defined as

```
status_t create_matrix_2(size_t dimension, int ***p) {
    if (!p) {
        return ERROR_NULL_POINTER;
    }
    if (!(*p = create_matrix(dimension))) {
        return ERROR_NO_MEMORY;
    }
    return SUCCESS_OR_SOMETHING;
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to return for success; your version (b) is missing a return statement there.

Comment: you're correct, *p[e] was a typo when typing this post, will edit. I'm using gcc version 7.4.0 with flags `-ansi -pedantic -Wall`. I don't understand what you mean by saying p is de-referenced before initialization, how should I adress this? Thanks

Comment: @JuanHirschmann See my fixed version. You need to assign a value to `p` before you can use the value of `p`. What is unclear about this?

Comment: @JuanHirschmann I've removed the `*p[e]` part of my answer, but I've found another issue: `e >= 0` is always true.